lldb running in REPL mode, need example REPL configuration file (android)
I have lldb 18.1.5 running on a Termux installation replete with multiple languages, but cannot get lldb -r -R "language" going for any of them. Apparently I need a config file .lldbinit-language-repl for each language, and I have not found any info about how to structure such a configuration file.
The details: I have installed Swift in my Android Termux environment in order to learn the language. Naturally, I'm eager to try the Swift REPL. However, it relies on lldb, a program I have not had occasion to use until now.
~ $ lldb -r -R XXXX
error: couldn't find a REPL for XXXX


What sort of basic config will I need in order to run lldb -r -R Language with a given language "Language"?
Apparently a REPL config file is required for each language, with a filename of this pattern: ".lldbinit-Language-repl"
This would be in my home directory... but touching an empty file was not enough. What does this file need to have in it... I can find documentation nowhere.
Also, is there supposed to be a default system-wide .lldbinit or lldbinit, and if so, where should it be located?
Is there a central location to put REPL files for all users?
This is Termux, so "all users" is a moot point, but I prefer to avoid cluttering my home directory with all sorts of frail config files I could destroy by accident.
If anyone could share the contents of a .lldbinit-something-repl file, for lldb 18.1.5 on any system but especially Termux or for the language Swift, I'd be grateful.
Or, if there is detailed file format documentation somewhere, that would be good too.
KWR

lldb's repl mode requires support in lldb itself, not just configuration files.  At present, the only REPL supported is Swift.  There's a sketch for C++ but I don't think anyone has made it actually work.
Also, the Swift REPL relies on having a Swift development environment available so the lldb's that are built to run in a device environment often have the REPL compiled out.  If just lldb -r doesn't bring up a swift REPL, then that's probably the case for you.
BTW, excuse the obvious, but you also have to get your lldb from the swift distro, the llvm.org ones have no swift support at all.
